# GET-параметры в адресе Joomla

Tags: joomla, get

Я уже замучился разбираться... Однако есть внутренний заказ и приходится работать.

Если кто знает, объясните, что это за параметры в адресах материалов и какие у них могут быть варианты значений:

```
option   // пример: com_content
view     // пример: article
id       // id материала, например, 43
catid    // id категории, например, 17
Itemid   // еще какой-то id, например, 133
```

Я в упор не понимаю логику таких адресов. Разве можно в Джумле добавить ссылку на что-то помимо материала (`view=article`)?

И разве при диком количестве таблиц Джумле не достаточно знать идентификатор материала, чтобы понять, к какой категории относится материал?

И зачем, ради всего святого, нужен этот параметр `Itemid`, пишущийся почему-то с прописной буквы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Преуведомление: я заменил в тексте ответа префиксы таблиц на ##.*

**Itemid** - это первичный ключ таблицы ##_menu. Этот идентификатор используется для определения способа отображения материала и для построения меню. Идея разработчиков Джумлы заключается в том, что к одному и тому же материалу можно прийти разными путями, соответственно из-за этого может измениться способ отображения материала. Самый простой пример - хлебные крошки: Если вы пришли на материал *Bar* из категории *Foo*, то хлебные крошки будут выглядеть так:

> Home -> **Foo** -> Bar

... если же пришли из категории Baz, то так:

> Home -> **Baz** -> Bar

В этой же таблице хранятся относительные ссылки, в моем случае - на материал:

> index.php?option=com_content&**view=article&id=44**

...и его алиас:

> foo/bar/baz/

Эта таблица позволяет Джумле восстановить реальный адрес материала при включенном SEF, и найти соответствующий идентификатор материала. *Странно, конечно, что Джумла хранит не внешний ключ, который мог бы связать пункт меню с контентом, а относительный адрес.*

Контент лежит в таблице **##_content**. Два поля из этой таблицы проявляются в адресе страницы: **id** и **catid**:

> index.php?option=com_content&view=article&**id**=44&**catid**=17&Itemid=144

*Id* - идентификатор материала, *catid* - идентификатор категории, который по сути является внешним ключом для связи с таблицей **##_categories**. Параметр *catid* необязателен: он не учитывается при выборе материала из базы. Скорее всего, атавизм, доставшийся в наследство от прошлых версий CMS.

Собрав данные из БД, Joomla готовит данные для отображения. Вот здесь используются оставшиеся два параметра: **option** и **view** - компонент и способ отображения компонента соответственно. Разновидности отображений в Джумле покрываются термином *layout*.

В структуре Джумлы есть директория \components\com_content\views, в которой есть несколько поддиректорий (версия 3.1):

1. archive - архивные материалы
2. article - материалы
3. categories - список всех категорий
4. category - список материалов категории (если добавить параметр layout=blog - блог категории)
5. featured - избранные материалы
6. form - форма для создания нового материала (+ параметр layout=edit)

*Буду рад дополнениям и уточнениям.*